# Angular router lazy loading: two different modules which start with the same path

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I have two modules each have two child routes.
First module uses routes like:
items/:id
items/:id/print

The second one:
items/:id/edit
items/:id/marketing

So I guess how to make a config for such a case:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        loadChildren: './features/item-details/item-details.module#ItemDetailsModule',
        path: 'items/:id'
    },
    {
        loadChildren: './features/item-management/item-management.module#ItemManagementModule',
        path: 'items/:id'
    }
];
```

I don't want to unite this two modules since it's almost nothing in common.
And also I am not happy with an idea to separate it to 4 different modules.

Comment: Whats the issue you have, it will work anyway.

Comment: Any specific reason for considering to create a separate module for this when you have everything in these related to `items`?

Comment: @SunilSingh I have updated my question. The problem is in the same path for different modules

Comment: @SiddAjmera Because those models are very different. I don't want to import the stuff for two of them which not needed for another two. That's goes to declare as well

Comment: If they have "almost nothing in common", why don't you simply use different routes for them ? What you are doing seems like a bad design, not an issue ...

Comment: You can have separate root paths for these two modules. Something like `items/details/:id'` and `items/management/:id'`.

Comment: @trichetriche
The project has those urls like 5 years already. I'm looking for a way to keep them.
This routing design wasn't a bad with old Angular.js. And I sincerely think that's it should be more flexible. The framework is mere a tool and it shouldn't dictate you what urls structure you should have.
Perhaps I will try to go with UrlMatcher

Comment: @DzmitryVasilevsky legacy code is no excuse for bad designs ... That's called refactoring and it's required to keep your code clean and up to date. And the framework can't go against common sense : one state (URL) = one component. It can't know which one to use, that's why you can use several URLS for that. Otherwise, you'll have to rely on dynamic components, or several router outlets.

Comment: @trichetriche It's not legacy code. It's legacy UI. Users expect to see the same urls.
one state (URL) !== one component actually since you can use child routes inside module.
And the conception can be implemented in style `path: '(items/:id)|(other-url)'`

Comment: Yeah sure buddy, whatever you say ... If you want to reach and keep being stubborn, I don't see why I should keep losing time here. Good luck with your project, hope you find a solution to your issue.

Comment: @trichetriche Sorry to disturb you. If you are curious there is a way, see below. I'm agree that your point is more beautiful but the workaround may be helpful.

Comment: CanLoad prevents routes from being loaded, that isn't its purpose, that's nasty ... But congratulations on that workaround, that's really well thought I have to admit :)

Comment: @trichetriche Thanks mentioning it. I have come with better solution.

Comment: @trichetriche Refactoring by definition means not changing behavior, just improving code. Asking them to change the routes is not a refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a way to do so with UrlMatcher. 
You can check a target url to load or not a module. 
https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher

```
const managmentMatcher = (segments: UrlSegment[]) => {

    return /^\/*items\/\d+\/(edit|marketings)\/*.test(segments.join('/')) ?
       { consumed: segments.slice(0, 2), posParams: { id: segments[1] } } : null;

}

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    // special routes
    {
        loadChildren: './features/item-management/item-management.module#ItemManagementModule',
        matcher: managmentMatcher
    },
    // default routing for items/:id
    {
        loadChildren: './features/item-details/item-details.module#ItemDetailsModule',
        path: 'items/:id'
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same path for different modules, why not switch the paths and you will have a more isolated module and separated of concerns.

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        loadChildren: './features/item-details/item-details.module#ItemDetailsModule',
        path: 'items/details/:id'
    },
    {
        loadChildren: './features/item-management/item-management.module#ItemManagementModule',
        path: 'items/management/:id'
    }
];
```

Comment: I know it's the best way if I was starting with it.    
But not really acceptable now because project in ongoing and current urls have being used for ages. I can add redirects for legacy support but I want to look for the way to implement it with existing urls